# Condition for $HKL$ to be a subgroup of G

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H,K,L$ are subgroups of $G$ then when will $HKL$ form a subgroup of G.

If there are two subgroups $H,K$ then $HK$ is a subgroup iff $HK = KH$.

But how can I generalize this for 3 or more  subgroups.

Comment: It's clearly sufficient if the three subgroups commute in pairs, i.e. $HK=KH$, $HL=LH$ and $KL=LK$. But that is not a necessary condition, because we could have $H=G$ and then $K$ and $L$ could be arbitrary subgroups which do not necessarily commute. I expect there are also examples in which $HKL=G$ but no pair of the subgroups commute. So I suspect that this question does not have an easily stated answer.

Comment: By the way, why the close vote? It seems a reasonable question!